# MySQL nested JSON column search and compare to with today's day

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7, json-extract

I am using MySQL Version 5.7.28. I am having json data like below.

```
CREATE TABLE `week2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` smallint(1),
  `json` text ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO week2(id,type,json)
VALUES
    (121,1,'[{"weekdays":"Sunday"},{"weekdays":"Monday"},{"weekdays":"Tuesday"},{"weekdays":"Wednesday"},{"weekdays":"Thursday"},{"weekdays":"Friday"},{"weekdays":"Saturday"}]'),
    (122,1,'[{"weekdays":"Sunday"},{"weekdays":"Monday"}]'),
    (123,2,'[{"start_time":"08:00 AM","end_time":"10:00 PM"}]');
```

As you see, the json column has nested JSON data. so here i am looking to compare today's day ( which is Saturday and we are currently in between start time and end time)

### Expected Result:

```
(121,1,'[{"weekdays":"Sunday"},{"weekdays":"Monday"},{"weekdays":"Tuesday"},{"weekdays":"Wednesday"},{"weekdays":"Thursday"},{"weekdays":"Friday"},{"weekdays":"Saturday"}]'),
(123,2,'[{"start_time":"08:00 AM","end_time":"10:00 PM"}]');
```

Comment: That `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements are erroneous...

Comment: Nope, it's still erroneous, see : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXz2s5uXRpWcRQHJ1syc9Y/0

Comment: it is corrected now.

Comment: what MySQL version

Comment: Mysql Version 5.7.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect day name **(1)** and time period **(2)**, and combine those two conditions by **OR** operator at the end.

For **(1)** : Detect the current day's name by using `DAYNAME()` function and search whether exists in the JSON data containing weekday keys through use of `JSON_CONTAINS` function.

For **(2)** : `TIME()` function and `CAST`ing strings to `TIME` data type might be used with a trick to add 12 hours iterations for the cases of `PM` type times.

So, consider using :

```
SELECT *
  FROM `week2`
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`json`->>'$[*].weekdays', CONCAT('"',DAYNAME( NOW() ),'"')) = 1
    OR
    (
      TIME(ADDTIME(NOW(),"8:00:00")) >=       
      CASE WHEN INSTR(REPLACE(`json`->>'$[0].start_time',"12:00 AM","00:00 AM"),"PM")>0 
           THEN 
                CAST(CONCAT(MOD((TIME_FORMAT(REPLACE(`json`->>'$[0].start_time',"12:00 AM","00:00 AM"), "%T")+12),24),":00 AM") 
                  AS TIME) 
           ELSE
                CAST((REPLACE(`json`->>'$[0].start_time',"12:00 AM","00:00 AM")) AS TIME)
            END    
   AND 
      TIME(ADDTIME(NOW(),"8:00:00")) <=
           CASE WHEN INSTR(REPLACE(`json`->>'$[0].end_time',"12:00 AM","00:00 AM"),"PM")>0 
           THEN 
                CAST(CONCAT(MOD((TIME_FORMAT(REPLACE(`json`->>'$[0].end_time',"12:00 AM","00:00 AM"), "%T")+12),24),":00 AM") 
                  AS TIME) 
           ELSE
                CAST(REPLACE(`json`->>'$[0].end_time',"12:00 AM","00:00 AM") AS TIME)                  
            END)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=eea0686d0f6d463e9e8d974936351f61)</kbd>

Comment: if we have time [{"start_time":"12:00 AM","end_time":"01:00 PM"}] it is not working..

Comment: No, yet there's no problem. Consider [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d7dcf1d14958400532bc5e36d18532d0) where both two rows return if `TIME(NOW())` is replaced with `TIME(ADDTIME(NOW(),"-7:00:00"))` currently depending on GMT @VishalTanna .

Comment: You can check this ==>  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1c0a974b901d6c1f6c3793275ff19952"

Comment: remove the plus sign preceding 8, and if you want to move forward in order to stay within this interval [consider using](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e73a75a3ef54c1212a5cc367bd2017ac) `TIME(ADDTIME(NOW(),"16:00:00"))` **currently**  @VishalTanna

Comment: Now you can compare this : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=791fcffe10e5b658d855cd7348c20060 and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2b2bcaae2a2637cd97100cdf8ce8a837 it is return only row from [{"start_time":"12:00 AM","end_time":"01:00 PM"}]

Comment: it's as expected. Since TIME(ADDTIME(NOW(),"8:00:00"))  would return 04:05:31 ,which is already not in this interval,  **currently** @VishalTanna , but **not** 12:05:31

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216788/discussion-between-vishal-tanna-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
SELECT *,CURRENT_TIME 
  FROM
(SELECT *,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`json`,'$[0].start_time')) AS st,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`json`,'$[0].end_time')) AS et FROM week2) V 
WHERE (JSON_SEARCH(`json`, 'one', DAYNAME(CURDATE()))  IS NOT NULL
       OR
     CURRENT_TIME hour >= 
      CASE WHEN st LIKE '%AM%' THEN REPLACE(st,' AM',':00') 
            WHEN st LIKE '%PM%' THEN SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(REPLACE(st,' PM',':00'))+43200)
            END
      AND
      CURRENT_TIME hour <=
      CASE WHEN et LIKE '%AM%' THEN REPLACE(et,' AM',':00') 
            WHEN et LIKE '%PM%' THEN SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(REPLACE(et,' PM',':00'))+43200)
            END);
```

First query is using [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) to extract the time and [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) to remove the (`"`) then make it as a sub-query.

On the outer-query, find the `weekdays` value using [JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) compare with today's `DAYNAME(CURDATE())`; if `JSON_SEARCH` doesn't find it, it will return `NULL`, hence the `IS NOT NULL` condition is used.

Append `OR` to compare `CURRENT_TIME` with the time value extracted from the `json` field. But first, using `CASE` expression to find out if it's `AM` or `PM`; if it's `AM`, just `REPLACE` the  `AM` with seconds hand (`:00`). If it's `PM`, do the `REPLACE` like `AM` then convert the time value to seconds using `TIME_TO_SEC` then add 43200 seconds (12 hours) and convert again to standard `hour:minute:second` format using `SEC_TO_TIME`.

P/S: It was my attempt to answer but I didn't post it because I get wrong result with the time.. Only when I put `CURRENT_TIME` in the fiddle that I realized that the fiddle time zone is different that mine. Also, I was testing on my local DB; which is MariaDB and the results of converting string to time using `STR_TO_TIME` is different. Honestly, in my opinion, if this is MariaDB, I think there's a chance that the query is much shorter.